# Is $\sqrt{m}$ irrational iff at least one prime occurs with an odd exponent in the factorisation of $m$?

Tags: prime-numbers, radicals, prime-factorization, rationality-testing

Thinking about it, I think I found the following criterion for irrationality of $\sqrt{m}$ if $m$ is a positive integer.

> Let $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ be the prime factorization of $m$. Then $\sqrt{m}$ is irrational if and only if $a_i$ is odd for at least one $1\le i\le k$.

Anyone knows if this is correct and, if so, a proof thereof?

Comment: Another way to say it is "$\sqrt{m}$ is irrational unless $m$ is a perfect square."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Since for any $p_i$ with power $a_i\geq 2$ you can put all except perhaps one outside the square root, it's enough to consider numbers where each prime factor has power $1$ (the so-called square free numbers). Thee question then translates to "The only square free number that has a rational square root is $1$" (I don't really know if $1$ is considered a square free number).

A variant on the proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ works fine.

Comment: Sure, $1$ is square-free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is true. A nice way to think about this, is that if you extend the notion of prime factorisation to allow for negative exponents, you can show that all rational numbers have a unique prime factorisation as well. Then if you square a rational number of the form $r=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the square of this has the unique prime factorisation

$$r^2=p_1^{2a_1}\cdots p_k^{2a_k}$$

So the square of any rational number has **only** even exponents in its prime factorisation. The converse is pretty obvious.

Note that from this line of thinking its easy to see that if $m$ is an integer, then $\sqrt{m}$ is either irrational or an integer too.